# Decreasing delay in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, input, delay

I am working on a small 2D game made in JavaFX, and for input (currently only moving the player around using WASD), there is a noticeable delay when switching directions quickly. Is there a way I can decrease this delay to where it isn't as noticeable, or a way to entirely delete the delay? I have seen some people use Timers to accomplish this, but I don't know how to use those. My code is below:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    public int direction;
    public KeyEvent key;

    public int playerX = 250;
    public int playerY = 250;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // Loads the grass block image
        Image grassImage1 = new Image(new FileInputStream("resources/textures/official/grass/grass32x32.png"));
        ImageView grassImageView = new ImageView(grassImage1);
        grassImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        grassImageView.setX(150);
        grassImageView.setY(50);

        // Loads the character image left side
        Image characterImgLeftNO = new Image(new FileInputStream("resources/textures/official/mainCharacter/mainCharLeftNO.png"));
        ImageView personImgViewLeftNO = new ImageView(characterImgLeftNO);
        personImgViewLeftNO.setPreserveRatio(true);
        personImgViewLeftNO.setX(playerX);
        personImgViewLeftNO.setY(playerY);

        // Loads the character image right side
        Image characterImgRightNO = new Image(new FileInputStream("resources/textures/official/mainCharacter/mainCharRightNO.png"));
        ImageView personImgViewRightNO = new ImageView(characterImgRightNO);
        personImgViewRightNO.setPreserveRatio(true);
        personImgViewRightNO.setX(playerX);
        personImgViewRightNO.setY(playerY);

        // Loads the character image back side
        Image characterImgBackNO = new Image(new FileInputStream("resources/textures/official/mainCharacter/mainCharBackNO.png"));
        ImageView personImgViewBackNO = new ImageView(characterImgBackNO);
        personImgViewBackNO.setPreserveRatio(true);
        personImgViewBackNO.setX(playerX);
        personImgViewBackNO.setY(playerY);

        // Loads the character image front side
        Image characterImgFrontNO = new Image(new FileInputStream("resources/textures/official/mainCharacter/mainCharFrontNO.png"));
        ImageView personImgViewFrontNO = new ImageView(characterImgFrontNO);
        personImgViewFrontNO.setPreserveRatio(true);
        personImgViewFrontNO.setX(playerX);
        personImgViewFrontNO.setY(playerY);

        // Creates a group with all of our sprites
        Group root = new Group(grassImageView, personImgViewLeftNO, personImgViewRightNO, personImgViewBackNO, personImgViewFrontNO);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);

        // Getting basic key presses, W, A, S, and D
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(e ->
        {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.W || e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP)
            {
                System.out.println("W key pressed, up");
                direction = 1;
                playerY -= 5;

                personImgViewLeftNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewRightNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewRightNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewFrontNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewBackNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewBackNO.setY(playerY);

                // Make anything but back view invisible
                personImgViewBackNO.setVisible(true);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewRightNO.setVisible(false);
            }
            else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.A || e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT)
            {
                System.out.println("A key pressed, left");
                direction = 2;
                playerX -= 5;

                personImgViewLeftNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewFrontNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewBackNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewBackNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewRightNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewRightNO.setY(playerY);

                // Make anything but Left invisible
                personImgViewBackNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setVisible(true);
                personImgViewRightNO.setVisible(false);
            }
            else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.S || e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN)
            {
                System.out.println("S key pressed, down");
                direction = 3;
                playerY += 5;
                personImgViewLeftNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewFrontNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewBackNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewBackNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewRightNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewRightNO.setY(playerY);


                // Make anything but front invisible
                personImgViewBackNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setVisible(true);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewRightNO.setVisible(false);
            }
            else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.D || e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT)
            {
                System.out.println("D key pressed, right");
                direction = 4;
                playerX += 5;

                personImgViewLeftNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewFrontNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewBackNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewBackNO.setY(playerY);

                personImgViewRightNO.setX(playerX);
                personImgViewRightNO.setY(playerY);

                // Make anything but right invisible
                personImgViewBackNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewFrontNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewLeftNO.setVisible(false);
                personImgViewRightNO.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        // Title for window
        stage.setTitle("Blocky");

        // Measurements for window
        stage.setMinWidth(640);
        stage.setMaxWidth(640);
        stage.setMinHeight(480);
        stage.setMaxHeight(480);
        stage.setWidth(640);
        stage.setHeight(480);

        scene.setFill(Color.WHITE);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, even if you don't have an answer for me.

Comment: Which system, which Java/JavaFX version? At a first glance I see nothing which could cause such a delay.

Comment: @mipa I'm using JavaFX 11, and my system is an HP Notebook 15. My problem is that whenever I am holding down one key (let's say W), whenever I switch to another key, there is a small delay (about a half of a second but it's extremely noticeable).

Comment: I doubt it will make a difference but why are you not using the latest version of JavaFX which is 14 and not 11. There is at least a chance that a bug has been fixed in the mean time. Upgrading to the latest version is always the first thing that one should try before starting a discussion.

Comment: @mipa I don't know exactly which version I'm using (I believe I downloaded 14 from Gluon) but the folder says javafx-sdk-11.0.2.

Comment: This is the old public version of 11. Why don't you use version 14 (or even 15 EA) from the same download page? https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ If you have a problem like yours it just does not make sense to stick to an old version and then ask for help here.

Comment: @mipa I'll get the new version, and see if it makes any difference.